# "+(up:number)" option in Tikz is not relative to the first coordinate?

Tags: tikz-pgf, relative

In **Tikz** package, one plus (**+**) represent the relarive coordinate to the first coordinate, but sometimes it is not the case. I see this example in **Tikz** pdf file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[place] (waiting) {};
\node[place] (critical) [below=of waiting] {};
\node[place] (semaphore) [below=of critical] {};
\node[transition] (leave critical) [right=of critical] {};
\node[transition] (enter critical) [left=of critical] {};
\draw [->] (enter critical) -- (critical);
\draw [->] (waiting) .. controls +(left:8mm) and +(up:8mm)
.. (enter critical);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the correct output should be:

[image]

In the code above, there is `+(up:8mm)`, which should be relative to `waiting` as there is only one **+**. But `waiting` is on the top most location, so `+(up:8mm)` would not be the coordinate above the `waiting`. So, how to understand the one plus (**+**) in `+(up:8mm)`?

Comment: The second control point is relativ to the target, here `critical`. This is also mentioned in the manual [about relative coordinates](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#sec-13.4.1). This is an exception to how relative coordinates work and a kind of different case of relative coordinates. The `++` doesn't do anything in this case either.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel  So, is there only two control points? If the curve is very long, and need many controls, what should we do?

Comment: The curve that is specified by `.. controls … ..` is a Bezier curve (of max degree 3), by definition that is a curve between two points using two control points. If you need a curve through more than two points you will need to use a different tool. Maybe [`hobby`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hobby) (see also tag [tag:hobby]) is what you need. But without more input from your side it's hard to say what you need.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Okay. I will try it.